# How to add a model inside another model with mongoose and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project and am trying to add a model inside another model but i can't seem to figure out how to do it. Have any suggestions?
`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: String,
    loc: String,
    title: String,
   passage: String,
   file: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Item = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);

const user1 = new User({
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "arbuckle",
    email: "blablabal@asdf",
    password: "123456789"
});

const item1 = new Item({
    date: "Today",
    loc: "here",
    title: "message",
    passage: "This is an example",
    file: "none"
});
```

I am wanting to add this model const `Item = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);` to the User model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

In userSchema add `items : { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Item' }`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    items : {
         type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
         ref: 'Item'
    }
});

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: String,
    loc: String,
    title: String,
   passage: String,
   file: String
});
```

Comment: I am not seeing the Item model go into the User model i see it outside but not inside.

Comment: What? I don't get it

Comment: I am going to try one more thing that might work using what you gave.

Comment: Read the population doc. When you query, Mongo will return populated User documents. Query with : `User.find({first_name: "John"}).populate("items")`

Comment: You see i just learned about mongoose and databases and I am still kind of new to it! I know how to add, remove, and edit and reference documents. Like I said I want to try something that might work, but it isn't going to be the most organized way of doing it.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: I also didn't go through all of it... I just looked through the document from the link you sent me and i think that will work.

Comment: Hold on I think i put the Item in the wrong place! I want to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Thille! I think I got it now! I appreciate you time and help.

Comment: When I am done with the app I can send you the link if you like?

Comment: Sure, I can have a look, see what I've helped build ;)

Comment: Ok I will do that! I just started using stackoverflow today so i am new to it.

Comment: Um how do you do that? How do you mark it as excepted?

Comment: There's a green check mark to the left of the answer

Comment: Do you want me to post the link on here when I am done?

Comment: Sure, leave it here

Comment: Ok I will do that when I am done which will probably be in a couple of days cause the app is the most complicated app that i have made.

Comment: By the way are you on github? I am... here is the link to my profile https://github.com/LublubXT

Comment: Not really, no... I don't use Github much. But I'll have a look at your profile

Comment: Also my website is here http://aztecteam.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Hi once again Mr. Thille here is the link to the app i finished it on saturday. Also my or our website link is here also:

Web: https://azitecteam.herokuapp.com
App: https://azitecteam.herokuapp.com/sermontrackerhome

Comment: Also if you go to the contact us there and me! Thanks!

Comment: Ha nice :) Congratulations! I visited both websites, well done!

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for your help as well!

Comment: I will try sending Photos of inside the Sermon Tracker app. If i can send images... I will have to figure it out.